# Find the moves between start and End

Tags: java

currently i am working with path finding game. i need  help to finish this small game.

here is my keys of path

```
S= starting point;

* = can move

# = blocker, you can’t move to it, must move around.

O=end point.
```

I need to go from S to O and i need to get number of moves to go from 'S' to 'O'.

```
    char[][] mygrid = {
    {'*', '*', '#', 'O', '*'},
    {'S', '#', '*', '*', '*'},
    {'*', '*', '*', '*', '*'}} ;
```

above is my 2D array in java. i need to find number of moves from 'S' to 'O'.

i am new bie for this forum. please help me to do this.

Comment: I am confused sir... need a starting point... :(

Comment: You just can't ask the SO community to do your assignment for you without showing at least some effort

Comment: you need a path finding algorithm, if you have no idea start with dijkstra, then move to a* (a-star)

Comment: @MartinFrank uhm Dijkstra is not really a path finding algorithm, rather a "shortest path picker" among a set of given arches.

Comment: i am going through path finding algorithm.

Comment: @Onheiron you are very right, but helps to understand basics on graph-theories (strongly required to advance further)

Comment: For a standard path finding algorithm, try Dijkstra’s algorithm. Your favourite search engine can no doubt find it.

Comment: The arcs/edges in Dijkstra’s algorithm are the legal moves in the game, that is, up, down, left and right except to and from blockers (`#`).

Answer (score 2):

You can fill all non-blocked cells around the start with `1`. Then fill with `2` all empty (not blocked and not start) cells around each of `1` cell. Around each of them - fill with `3` (except of `1`, block and start). repeat until there no more empty cells around last number or you get to the end. the number at the end cell will be the result.

```
{'1', '*', '#', 'O', '*'}    {'1', '2', '#', 'O', '*'}    {'1', '2', '#', 'O', '*'}
{'S', '#', '*', '*', '*'}    {'S', '#', '*', '*', '*'}    {'S', '#', '*', '*', '*'}
{'1', '*', '*', '*', '*'}    {'1', '2', '*', '*', '*'}    {'1', '2', '3', '*', '*'}

{'1', '2', '#', 'O', '*'}    {'1', '2', '#', 'O', '*'}    {'1', '2', '#', 'O(6)', '*'}
{'S', '#', '4', '*', '*'}    {'S', '#', '4', '5', '*'}    {'S', '#', '4', '5', '6'}
{'1', '2', '3', '4', '*'}    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}    {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}
```